# How to read multiple yaml definitions with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Is it possible to read multiple yaml definitions from a single file?

Example code:

```py
import ruamel.yaml

text = '''
---
foo: bar
---
baz: baz
...
'''

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
yamlFile = yaml.load(text)
```

Expected behavior is something like:

```py
for i in yamlFile:
  print(i) #foo: bar, baz: baz
```

Actual behavior is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/bruno.miranda/Desktop/iac/iac-wrapper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 434, in load
    return constructor.get_single_data()
  File "/Users/bruno.miranda/Desktop/iac/iac-wrapper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 120, in get_single_data
    node = self.composer.get_single_node()
  File "/Users/bruno.miranda/Desktop/iac/iac-wrapper/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py", line 81, in get_single_node
    raise ComposerError(
ruamel.yaml.composer.ComposerError: expected a single document in the stream
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 1:
    foo: bar
    ^ (line: 3)
but found another document
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 1:
    ---
```

Also tried without the `typ='rt'` on constructor but I have the same results.

Version that I'm using is:

```
pip show ruamel.yaml
Name: ruamel.yaml
Version: 0.17.16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from `.load()` there is `.load_all()` that gives an iterator over all the loaded data, one per document.

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
for data in yaml.load_all():
    do_your_thing_with(data)
```